# Optimizing Memory-Intensive Parallel Processing in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, synchronization

I've been working on a project involving memory-intensive parallel processing in Python 3.x, utilizing the `multiprocessing` module. The task at hand requires processing a large dataset that doesn't fit entirely in memory. After experimenting with `multiprocessing.Pool`, I've encountered memory issues due to the dataset being duplicated across processes.

In my attempt to mitigate this, I considered leveraging shared memory techniques such as `multiprocessing.shared_memory` or memory-mapped files using `mmap`. However, I'm uncertain about the optimal implementation for my specific scenario. Additionally, potential synchronization problems and the impact of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) on multi-process execution are concerns.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```py
import multiprocessing

def process_data(chunk):
    # Process the data chunk
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = ...  # Large dataset
    chunk_size = len(data) // multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
        pool.map(process_data, [data[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(data), chunk_size)])
```

**What I expected:**
I expected the code to efficiently distribute the data chunks across processes, avoiding excessive memory usage. Each process would process its assigned chunk of data, leveraging parallel processing capabilities, and ideally reducing memory overhead.

**What actually happened:**
However, due to the way Python's multiprocessing works, the `data` object is being duplicated across processes, leading to high memory consumption. Additionally, I'm unsure about the best approach to handle synchronization among processes and how to address the potential limitations imposed by the GIL.

I'm seeking advice, code examples, and best practices to address these challenges and achieve memory-efficient parallel processing in Python 3.x. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiprocessing is really nothing about reducing memory use. Usually the contrary: you use *more* RAM. In your program, your initial

```py
data = ...  # Large dataset
```

line, all by itself, already consumes more memory than you have. Split it into `K` chunks and spread those across additional processes, and it will take (at least) twice as much RAM. Those chunks are created *in addition to* the original `data` blob.

If you want to cut memory, the most effective way is to, in some app-specific way, pass a brief description of the data to access to worker functions, and let them retrieve the data themselves, outside of the multiprocessing machinery, Can't suggest something specific, because you've told us nothing specific about the nature of your `data`. Details are close to everything here.

Instead I'll give complete working code for a contrived problem where the answers are easy ;-) The task is to sum all the integers in a binary file of unsigned 64-bit ints stored in little-endian format (remember me aaying "details are close to everything here"? I wasn't joking).

No matter how large the file, the program here consumes little RAM:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

FNAME = "ints.dat"
N = 200_000_000
NWORKERS = 4

ismain = __name__ == "__main__"
if ismain:
    # create data
    print(f"writing out {N:_} fat ints to {FNAME!r}")
    with open(FNAME, "wb") as f:
        for i in range(N):
            f.write(i.to_bytes(8, "little"))
    print(f"done - flle has size {os.path.getsize(FNAME):_} bytes")

def summer(args):
    start, num = args
    with open(FNAME, "rb") as f:
        f.seek(8 * start)
        return sum(int.from_bytes(f.read(8), "little")
                   for _ in range(num))

if ismain:
    CHUNK = 1_000_000
    assert N % CHUNK == 0
    with mp.Pool(NWORKERS) as pool:
        it = pool.imap_unordered(summer,
                                 ((start, CHUNK)
                                  for start in range(0, N, CHUNK)))
        got = sum(it)
    expected = N * (N-1) // 2
    assert expected == got
    print(f"got {expected=:_}")
```

That's far from the most efficient way to solve this problem, but the point here isn't peak speed but rather to flesh out what "pass a brief description of the data to access to worker functions" means.

About the GIL, that can be supremely relevant for multi-threaded Python, but is irrelevant for multi-processing CPython. The main program, and each worker process in a `Pool`, has its own GIL, and they have nothing to do with each other. No cross-talk at all among them. A GIL affects only the process it belongs to.

There's a library of books about "synchronization", which is a very large, and potentially very involved, topic. You can very often just ignore it in CPython by sticking to `Pool` functions, and/or multiprocessing `Queue`s. They implement all the under-the-covers synchronization needed to support their advertised behaviors.